# Drupal 7 add node - Select boxes in three columns (admin form)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to break a huge select box list into three columns and I was wondering if this is possible via display suite or any other module. The next solution is to create a web form but taking in account that I am not so experienced theming it it would be nice if I could have some reference.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXxYN.png)

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHr0M.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) for the whole layout of the form as well as [GentleSelect](https://www.drupal.org/project/gentleselect) for the Category Selection. This is possible by just using Display Suite. I usedGentleSelect that gives a bit of better taste regarding the UI.

Hope this helps.